# Launch a Remark .rez file from browser

Tags: html, iis

I have an automation file created with Remark in Windows10. It's extension is rez. I want to launch it in it's own window from a HTML page hosted localy on IIS. Is it any way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch"?

Answer (score 0):

A .rez file is an automation Remark file, a sort of a script. Launching it means open it for running in Remark context.